# Is using Outlook 365 with identical email accounts on two different servers possible?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365

Our company currently runs two bare metal servers. Each server has its own installation of Exim (although Exim likely isn't the problem here).

Let's call them:

`mail1.domain.com`

`mail2.domain.com`

Both servers have identical email addresses and passwords configured for all of our team's accounts.

For years I've been using Outlook 2010 and I've always simply added them as `mail1` and `mail2` as two separate accounts; it's worked great. One account, `mail1.domain.com` would receive firewall and system-related email while `mail2.domain.com` would receive all team-related email. So it's the same email address, same password, but different incoming & outgoing servers configured in Outlook, which always resulted in two separate accounts.

However, I recently upgraded to Outlook 365 and now I'm having trouble creating the separate accounts. Outlook 365 either attempts to merge them into a single account, or in the case of another team member, won't allow him to create the second account for `mail2.domain.com` resulting in an "Email already added" error when attempting to use the "File > Add Account" wizard to add the second account. Not sure why it would matter, but I'm using IMAP and he's using POP.

I may have to try Thunderbird for one account and Outlook for the other; don't' want to do that.

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create shared mailbox with separate names and attach it to the desired team members? If not, best to contact Microsoft support through your Admin portal.

Comment: to be honestly i agree with jurajb if you migrate to a new service you want to get rid of the old stuff. so plan first and migrate the accounts to a single one. no person is needing 2 accound for 2 mail servers for 1 addresses

Comment: Agree with JurajB, shared mailbox seems to be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation and was wondering if you found a solution, other than using an older version of Outlook.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/513917)

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts to use Outlook's option to "set up my account manually" Outlook continued to take over and "detected" my incoming/outgoing settings based on the email address (which was the same on the two servers). After my unsuccessful attempts, I allowed 365 to create the two accounts the way it wanted to then I manually changed the incoming/outgoing servers. After that, Outlook separated them as it had in previous versions. Note: I was only able to get this working with IMAP. That said, I agree with the others. Having the same email account on two servers is not ideal but for now, that's what I needed to do.